# Interface builder auto constraint - How to remove automatic constraints?

Tags: ios, resize, interface-builder

I'm using a custom object (split button) in my .xib file. When you tap on the right side of the button, a view slides up from behind to display more controls. With autolayout enabled on my main view, interface builder assumes that I would like the top aligned with another button within the same horizontal plane. This is fine and dandy until the button goes to expand from 32px high to 124px and the auto-constraints force the button to fit into it's old frame that is aligned with the other button. I've tried to drop the priority of the constraint, but that just ends up moving the button's (x, y) coordinates and halving it's height. Is there anyway to disable specific constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Just if you need it, select the auto constraint you want to remove. In the Attributes Inspector, toggle the "Standard" option, and that will change your constraint icon colour to blue. Then, you can delete it!

Comment: i was doing that, it kept re-adding the constraint though

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem by setting the frame in my .xib to be the expanded size, and then using this method:

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (![self isSelected] && point.y < 96) 
        return NO;
    else 
        return YES;
}
```

I also learned that the more constraints you set, the more auto constraints you can remove.